# Adobe Illustrator: Inexplicable Transparency

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to work on an SVG-File I downloaded from here: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Risk_board.svg

I opened it in Illustrator and removed everything but the strokes. But there's a problem, there is some inexplicable transparency on the lines. Opacity is set to 100%, Blending Mode is "Normal", but see for yourself:

[image: Transparency Effect on the overlap of two lines]

Can you help me remove this effect?

Edit: 
Selected a line in the screenshot and here's a dropbox link to the actual file I'm working on: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y3hghnja22t0wkg/risk_map_001.ai?dl=0

Comment: Really impossible to determine without seeing a screenshot *with a line selected*.

Comment: Alright, changed the picture and added a link to the original *.ai-File, hope that helps!

Comment: If you just select a path and look at the **Appearance Panel** it generally tells you everything you need to know.... [**SEE HERE**](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iK16R.jpg) Selecting the group (as in your updated screenshot) is still of little help. If you have a problem with a path, you should select the path.

Comment: OK thanks, I figured it out! I actually watched the appearance panel, but with the group selected. It showed me "Opacity: Default", which was set to 100%. The single paths, however, had a different Opacity setting then the group, it was set to 59%. I'm still a little confused with that layer-sublayer-group-path-structure, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction Scott, appreciate it!

Comment: If you found the solution to your own question, please consider adding it as an answer and marking it accepted. That way, future visitors with the same problem are helped as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (the white arrow) to select a path, then just look at the **Appearance Panel**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can you help me remove this effect?

**To fix this in 2 minutes,** you can select all the lines, and go in the menu "object" and then "flatten transparency".

Then you can fill these paths with a new color at 100% and it should work. Everything will still be in vector. And you won't need to verify each line's opacity; it's a very fast way to get rid of the issue.

What you see on the image attached is the result. Make sure to have the box "preserve alpha transparency" **unchecked**! Otherwise it will keep the transparency!

[image: How to remove transparency from paths in Adobe Illustrator]

++++++

This is a quick way to fix all the transparency issues for the paths and it can also help if the vector uses a brush stroke (as found in the brush library) and to flatten their transparency effect.

Comment: Why the downvote? Because it fixes the issue in 2 minutes instead of selecting each path individually for 3 hours? From what I've seen, you cannot select all the paths together and change their transparency together and so quickly; it seems like using the "appearance" panel is useful for a few paths (one by one) but not for a map with dozens or hundreds of paths!